# PHP include a file with an included file -> scripts and variables get included but seem echo'd

Tags: php, include

I am having troubles with including a file that has an included file with some js script library's in it.

index.php

```
<?php
include 'header.php';
?>
<section>
  <div>
     <p>misc. html</p>
  </div>
</section>
<?php
include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/footer.php');
echo 'test ='.$testVar;
?>
```

footer.php

```
<?php
include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/footerscripts.php');
?>
</body>
</html>
```

/includes/footerscripts.php

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
$testVar = 'test';
?>
```

In that scenario, the index file does have this in the source code when ran:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
test =
```

The scripts are making their way there but are not being executed and the variables aren't coming through either.

When I change the footer.php to include those scripts and variable directly, the variable makes it to index.php, so do the scripts but they don't execute (or not on time?).

Any ideas guys?

I have a weird php5.ini file as I didn't know what all to put in it, if that makes a difference. The include file path seems okay as it still works for the most part.

Thanks,
Matt

Edit: Added the include ('header.php') which works fine and pulls in my header.

That file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="--">
<meta name="keywords" content="--">
<meta name="author" content="--">
<title>--</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mainstylesheet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="nav-top" id="top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="home-link">
                <a href="../"><img src="/images/logo/logo-p.png" alt="plc" class="logo" /></a>
            </div>
            <nav class="nav-main">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="../">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Edit: Guess I just needed my jquery loaded from the header of the document, because it works that way. I still can't carry variables from grandchild to parent but oh well

Comment: Change your `include` to `require` and watch where it fails.

Comment: I did, it doesn't fail, the jqery and bootstrap.js files just don't execute

Comment: `$_SERVER['ROOT']` Thinking you mean: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Answer (score 0):

According to your example the `index.php` file is missing something:

```
<?php
include ($_SERVER['ROOT'].'/footer.php');
echo 'test ='.$testVar;
?>
```

I assume that you didn't post the whole file, since here the output hmtl here is not valid - missing `html` opening tag, etc. Could you please provide the whole and/or simplified index file?

Answer (score 0):

Replace all instances of `$_SERVER['ROOT']` with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

Comment: Yeah, I caught that. Thanks.
It's still not working however. 
Shouldn't I be able to load some js library's this way before the /body tag?